# How to get the integer portion of a float column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Suppose I have a dataframe df as shown below

```
    qty
0   1.300
1   1.909
```

Now I want to extract only the integer portion of the qty column and the df should look like

```
   qty
0   1
1   1
```

Tried using df['qty'].round(0) but didn't get the desired result as it rounds of the number to the nearest integer.

Java has a function intValue() which does the desired operation. Is there a similar function in pandas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert values to integers by [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['qty'] = df['qty'].astype(int)
print (df)
   qty
0    1
1    1
```

If not working above is possible use [`numpy.modf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.modf.html) for extract values before `.`:

```
a, b = np.modf(df['qty'])
df['qty'] = b.astype(int)
print (df)
   qty
0    1
1    1
```

Or by split before `.`, but it should be slow if large DataFrame:

```
df['qty'] = b.astype(str).str.strip('.').str[0].astype(int)
```

Or use [`numpy.floor`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.floor.html):

```
df['qty'] = np.floor(df['qty']).astype(int)
```

Comment: It rounds of the float to nearest integer. For ex: 1.909 is converted to 2

Comment: @GopalChandak - tested with `1.999999` and returned `1`, but added another 2 solutions.

Comment: With astype solution it might be the version issue as suggested by @MykolaZotko

Comment: @GopalChandak - Maybe simplier should be `df['qty'] = np.floor(df['qty']).astype(int)`

Comment: Yeah @jezrael, the above solution seems much simpler. Thanks

Comment: @GopalChandak - Only one aswer should be accepted, not both

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `floordiv`:

```
df['col'].floordiv(1).astype(int)
```

For example:

```
        col
0  9.748333
1  6.612708
2  2.888753
3  8.913470
4  2.354213
```

Output:

```
0    9
1    6
2    2
3    8
4    2
Name: col, dtype: int64
```