# How to check if only the integer portion of the elements in two pandas data columns match?

Tags: python, pandas

I checked the answer here but this doesn't work for me.

[How to get the integer portion of a float column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60257537/how-to-get-the-integer-portion-of-a-float-column-in-pandas)

As I need to write further conditional statements which will perform operations on the exact values in the columns and the corresponding values in other columns.

So basically I am hoping that for my two dataframes df1 and df2 I will form a concatenated dataframe using

```
dfn_c = pd.concat([dfn_1, dfn_2], axis=1)
```

then write something like

```
dfn_cn = dfn_c.loc[df1.X1.isin(df2['X2'])]
```

where X1 and X2 are the said columns respectively. The above line of course makes an exact comparison whereas I want to compare only the integer portion and then form the new dataframe.

Comment: Please include a small subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, try casting to `int` then compare.

```
dfn_cn = dfn_c.loc[df1['X1'].astype(int).isin(df2['X2'].astype(int))]
```